# Android animation only shows the last ArrayList element

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-animation

I have 5 TextView fields that are meant to display a String and change the text every 10 seconds.
In order to make the change I have an AsyncTask that grabs the next 5 messages (doInBackground) and passes them to onPostExecute to be displayed in the UI.

When I display the messages without an animation, everything works perfectly fine and the messages rotate every 10 seconds via a new AsyncTask every time.
Now, when I attempt to use a simple fade-in/out animation on the TextViews, I can see all of them fading out and then back in with a placeholder string however the actual text messages I want to display are only displayed in the last TextView.

The AsyncTask is an inner-class of my MainActivity.java.
I have implemented an AnimationListener in MainActivity.java and due to that the objects below in onPostExecute (*(TextView) mNextTextView* & *(String) mNextMessageToDisplay*) are also declared as global variables in the main class.

Here's AsyncTask's onPostExecute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> mFiveMessagesToDisplay) {
    super.onPostExecute(mFiveMessagesToDisplay);

    for (int mTextViewCounter = 0; mTextViewCounter < 5; mTextViewCounter++) {
        // Prepare the next TextView and message to use
        mNextTextViewToUse = mTextViewArrayList.get(mTextViewCounter);
        mNextMessageToDisplay = mFiveMessagesToDisplay.get(mTextViewCounter);

        // Post and animate the message changes in the TextView
        mNextTextViewToUse.startAnimation(mFadeOutAnimation);
    }
}
```

And my AnimationListener:

```
private AnimationListener mFadeOutAnimListener = new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        mNextTextViewToUse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mNextTextViewToUse.setText(mNextMessageToDisplay);
        mNextTextViewToUse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mNextTextViewToUse.startAnimation(mFadeInAnimation);
    }
}
```

As you can see, my setText() method is applied on the mNextTextViewToUse object with the contents of mNextMessageToDisplay, which are as mentioned before both global variables in the main class.

Both ArrayLists, the one containing the messages and the other containing the correct, I have iterated over both and printed the contents - everything is in its place.
Reminding again that if I use setText() with the same TextView and String objects under onPostExecute, everything works perfectly fine just without the animation.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I ended up completely removing the FOR loop logic and using recursion which raises a Boolean flag once it has used all 5 available TextViews.

The method that gets the next TextView and String message and execute the animated setText():

```
public void updateTextView(List<String> mMessages) {
    mNextTextViewToUse = mTextViewArrayList.get(mCurrentMessageIndex);
    mNextMessageToDisplay = mMessages.get(mCurrentMessageIndex);

    mNextTextViewToUse.startAnimation(mFadeOutAnimation);
    if (mCurrentMessageIndex == 4) {
        mStopMessageDisplayRepeat = true;
    } else {
        mCurrentMessageIndex++;
    }
}
```

The Runnable that calls the method above, while the recursion stop Boolean is false:

```
public Runnable mUpdateTextViewRunnable = new Runnable() {
    final static int POSTDELAY_INTERVAL = 600;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateTextView(mFiveMessages);
        if (! mStopMessageDisplayRepeat) {
            mMessageDisplayRepeatHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTextViewRunnable, POSTDELAY_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
};
```

Execute the Runnable:

```
public void startTextViewRunnableRepeat() {
    mUpdateTextViewRunnable.run();
}
```

This is how my AsyncTask's onPostExecute() looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> mFiveMessagesToDisplay) {
    super.onPostExecute(mFiveMessagesToDisplay);

    mFiveMessages = mFiveMessagesToDisplay; 
    startTextViewRunnableRepeat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the loops finishes by the time the animation ends, that's why you see only the last message. 
Lets say that mNextTextViewToUse points to TextView1. You start a fade out animation for this TextView. By the time the animation ends, mNextTextViewToUse points to a different textView object (because the loop continue to run while the fade out animation is playing) so when onAnimationEnd is being called (by the fade out animation of TextView1) mNextTextView points to TextView5, and basically you are setting the text to this text view only.

There are several ways to solve this / implement what you need, personally I would probably create my own TextView class (extending TextView of course) and I'll add a public method called setTextAnimated (String newText). It will look something like:

```
public void setTextAnimated (String newText) {
    mNextText = newText;
    startAnimation(mFadeOutAnim);          
}
```

where your onAnimationEnd callback will simple call setText(mNextText) and then will start fade-in animation.

Using this you will avoid another issue - that if you use the same animation object on different views - they will share the same timeline and interpolator. The result is that if View1 start a fade out animation that should take 200ms, and View 5 starts the same animation after 140ms, View5 will immediately "jump" to the same alpha value that View1 is.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested above, thing is that both my references to the next TextView and next message to display are global variables in the main activity class, even if I pass the String value to the setTextAnimated() method in my implementation of TextView, it can't assign that String to the String i need to use for setText() in the loop. Do you know of a way I can make the for loop pause for the duration of my animation and have the code continue when onAnimationEnd is called?